# Add the multiples of 3 and 5 till n

Tags: java, algorithm

This is my first query, hope I am answered appropriately. This is a question from hackerrank website.

Question: Add the multiples of 3 and 5 together uptill "N"

Sample Input 0

100

Sample Output 0

2318

My Code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        int sum=0,j=3,k=5;
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++)
        {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            
            while(j<n)
            {
                sum=sum+j;
                
                j+=3;
            

            }
            while(k<n)
            {
                sum=sum+k;
                k+=5;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
            sum=0;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is giving me a wrong output. Please attend to this problem.

Comment: 'Add the multiples of 3 and 5 together uptill "N"' what is the actual expected output and why?

Comment: Expected/ sample output is given above. I am getting an output of 2610.

Comment: "This is my first query, hope I am answered appropriately" - if it were my first question I'd hope what I wrote was appropriate :) - Please read [ask] on how to write good and appropriate questions.

Comment: Add a link to hackerrank.

Comment: 15 (and all other multiples of 3 AND 5) is added twice which is probably incorrect...

Comment: One thing you might do is map out your algorithm on paper. What multiples of 3 and 5 do you have? Could there be some that are both (e.g. 15)? Would you want to add them twice?

Comment: Yes thank you. I got my mistake.

Comment: If I may suggest something for future programs: names are important for understanding your own code. May it be variable or method or class names. Give them clear names (`i,j,k` are fine for indices but otherwise avoid simple letters), you may also try avoiding numbers in names (*what could be the difference between `a0` and `a1`? what  happens to `a1` when you remove `a0`?*) . And finally, don't declare your variables in a single line `int i,j,k,l`; it's difficult to read and refactor, especially when your programs grow larger and more complex. Just some advice :)

Comment: Count the multiples of 3, add the multiples of 5, subtract the multiples of 15 (this is the inclusion/exclusion principle).

Answer (score 1):

To know if a number is a multiple of another, the easiest way is to divide one by the other and check the modulo. You never do that.

I would suggest something like that :

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static final int THREE = 3;
    private static final int FIVE = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        int sum=0;

        for(int a0 = 0; a0 <= t; a0++)
        {

            if (a0 % THREE == 0 || a0 % FIVE == 0) {
                sum += a0;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly a typo, method `main` does not have to be generic

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, I used a code sample from another question. I will edit it.

Comment: looks like a good solution!

Comment: I had used this logic earlier. Thank you.